# Customize Grunt messages in Command line

Tags: gruntjs

I am using Grunt mainly for Sass and when I got an error message I am wasting too much time looking at all that text Grunt is giving me and trying to find where is the problem. Is there a way to get rid of all unnecessary lines?

I just need a message for:

- Success / Fail
- completed in 8.7s
- (if error) what line in which file is causing the problems

[image]

I usually have this

```
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

Comment: Try the `quiet` param for the plugin if you're using `grunt-contrib-sass`, ref: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Comment: Thank you, I am not using grunt-contrib-sass though

Comment: ok, well there's similar properties for `grunt-contrib-compass`, ref: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: If you can't obtain the desired logging output with the property options that the plugin exposes, you'll either need to find a similar plugin that can provide that, or customize the plugin yourself